# Being DRY in a Sqlite query with CASE statement

Tags: sqlite, case, dry

In the following (working) query:

```
SELECT q.id, q.section_id, q.type, q.required, q.condition,
CASE WHEN (t1.text_1 IS NULL) THEN
    CASE WHEN ((SELECT t2.text_1 FROM translations t2 WHERE t2.item_id = q.id AND t2.item_model = 'questions' AND t2.language = 'en' LIMIT 1) IS NULL) THEN 
        (SELECT t3.text_1 FROM translations t3 WHERE t3.item_id = q.id AND t3.item_model = 'questions' LIMIT 1)
    ELSE
        (SELECT t2.text_1 FROM translations t2 WHERE t2.item_id = q.id AND t2.item_model = 'questions' AND t2.language = 'en' LIMIT 1)
    END
ELSE
    t1.text_1
END
AS translation
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN translations t1 ON t1.item_id = q.id
    AND t1.item_model = 'questions'
    AND t1.language = 'fr'
ORDER BY q.position
```

You can see that the part `(SELECT t2.text_1 FROM translations t2 WHERE t2.item_id = q.id AND t2.item_model = 'questions' AND t2.language = 'en' LIMIT 1)` is repeated twice (the first to check if it's null, and the second to get the value).

Could the repeated same query a performance issue (I guess so)?
Is there a better way to rewrite this query, being DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the inner `CASE` statement with `coalesce()` function:

```
coalesce(SELECT t2.text_1 FROM translations t2 WHERE t2.item_id = q.id AND t2.item_model = 'questions' AND t2.language = 'en' LIMIT 1,
SELECT t3.text_1 FROM translations t3 WHERE t3.item_id = q.id AND t3.item_model = 'questions' LIMIT 1)
```

From the [documenation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce):

> **coalesce(X,Y,...)**
>
> The coalesce() function returns a copy of its first non-NULL argument,
>   or NULL if all arguments are NULL. Coalesce() must have at least 2
>   arguments.

Similar is the [ifnull()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) function.

Comment: This is GREAT! You just saved my day also on another query with 3 coalesce argumenst! :-)